# normal approximation to the binomial distribution in fair die

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

Suppose a fair die is independently tossed 1000 times.

(a)  Use the normal approximation to approximate the probability that the number 1 appears at least 180 times.

(b)  Use the normal approximation to approximate the probability that odd outcomes for the die (1,3,5) appear between 480 and 510 times (both 480 and 510 are included).

(a)
Since,
$$p = {1\over 6} , n= 1000$$
I calculated that: $$μ = {500\over 3}, σ = {50\sqrt{2}\over 6} $$

Since I am asked to use normal approximation:

$$P(X\geq180) 
= P(X> 179.5)
= P(Z>{179.5 - μ\over σ}) 
= 1 - Φ(1.088944) 
= 0.1381$$

(b)
Since,
$$p = {1\over 2} , n= 1000$$
I calculated that: $$μ = 500, σ = {5\sqrt{10}} $$

$$P(480 \leq X \leq 510) 
= P(479.5 < X < 510.5) = P({479.5 - μ\over σ} < Z < {510.5 - μ\over σ})$$

Thus, we get:

$$Φ(0.664078309) - Φ(-1.29653384) = 0.7467 - 0.0974 = 0.6493 $$

Are all my steps and answers correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to (a) looks reasonable - the exact binomial probability is closer to $0.18343$,  but you were asked for an approximation. The continuity correction is sensible. In R:

```
1 - pbinom(179, 1000, 1/6)
# 0.1384309
1 - pnorm(179.5, 1000/6, sqrt(1000*1/6*5/6))
# 0.1380892
```

Your approach  to (b) is also reasonable including the continuity correction, and the exact binomial probability is about $0.649287$ compared to your calculation of $0.649284$.  In R

```
sum(dbinom(480:510, 1000, 3/6))
# 0.6492868
pnorm(510+0.5, 1000/2, sqrt(1000/4)) - pnorm(480-0.5, 1000/2, sqrt(1000/4))
# 0.6492841
```

(I had originally misread the question, thinking you only wanted odd numbers between $480$ and $510$ so $481,483, \ldots, 509$.  If that had been the case, there are $15$ odd numbers between $480$ and $510$, while $510-480 = 30$, so perhaps you want to approximate about half of the probability in this interval, without any further continuity correction. So you might have used something like $\frac12\left(\Phi\left(\frac{510-500}{5 \sqrt{10}}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{480-500}{5 \sqrt{10}}\right)\right) \approx 0.31675$ while the exact binomial probability would have been closer to $0.31686$.)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the reply. Can I ask why you would only consider the odd outcomes for X? The question is asking for the number of odd rolls(1,3,5) so I don't see the rationale for only considering the outcomes in which X is odd(481,483,...).

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading it -  I though it meant $481,483,$ etc.  If not then your approach  to (b) is also reasonable including the continuity correction, and the exact binomial probability is about $0.649287$ compared to your calculation of $0.649284$

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I worded part (b) poorly, I can see how one might misunderstand the question. Will edit the main post to eliminate any ambiguity. Thanks.

Comment: Not your fault: I have edited my answer to confirm everything you did was sensible